# not clearly understand onclick behavior for group

Tags: kineticjs

I have a group, that contains a rectangle and text on it. Also i have added an onclick listener on group.
In its callback function i added code for checking what target is clicked:

```
            this.cell_group[x][y].on('click', function(evt) {
                node = evt.targetNode;
                alert(node.getName());
```

After that i receive 'rectangle' if i click on part of rectangle, or 'text' if i click on text.
I want to get group as targetNode, then to get child text object to change it.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `this` inside the eventHandler function to address the group on which the click event has happened.

Now within the eventHandler, depending upon how you have added text box, you can either use `this.getChildren()`[[see here]](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#getChildren) and loop through the children to find your text box

**OR**

simply use `this.get()` [[see here]](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#get) function to directly find the required node.